# Does this Graph definition work?

Tags: graph-theory

I've seen a lot of different definitions of graph, but this one made me think a lot.

"A graph is a pair $(V,E)$ such that $E$ is an irreflexive and symmetric relation in $V\neq\varnothing$."

Does this definition work? I thought it'd be better to make an equivalence relation within $E$ being the irreflexive and symmetric relation, making the partition $\{\{(a,b),(b,a)\}\mid (a,b)\in E\}$ and letting this partition be the new edge set $E'$. But this definition is too weird.

I think it's an attempt to making a simple definition complicated...

Comment: You need to define $(a,b)$ though! Remember that $E$ is actually a subset of $V\times V$, otherwise you reference $E$ in its construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is good.  What this means is that each pair $(a,b)\in V\times V$ is an edge.

Irreflexive means that you have no loops, i.e., edges of the form $(a,a)$.

Symmetric means that if you have $(a,b)$, then you have $(b,a)$.  This describes an undirected edge.

This definition is describing (characterizing) the types of relations that you can have as a possible $E$.

Your definition looks like you're defining $E$ in terms of itself and your description appears to be focusing on the symmetric property, not that there are no loops.  You could change your definition to be that $E$ is a subset of $((V\times V)\setminus\Delta)/\sim$ where $\Delta$ is the diagonal of the product ($\Delta=\{(a,a):a\in V\}$).  Then, the equivalence relation that you describe is $\sim$.

Comment: I didn't mean that. I meant using the previous definition of the edge set: "$E$ is an irreflexive and symmetric relation in $V\neq\varnothing$." to build a new edge set in which I don't have two elements to say the same (The elements (a,b) and (b,a)).

Comment: Then, yes, your edges can be equivalence classes of the irreflexive and symmetric $E$.

Comment: @DavidMolano The original definition of $E$ treats each undirected edge as a pair of directed edges while your equivalence relation is identifying (collapsing) the directed edges into an undirected edge.